# Rejected edit which contains related link

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

What is the rationale behind the decision to reject an edit which adds a link that is related to the question and the (*edited*) answer ?

A few minutes ago I edited [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4877628) with a link to a github page, which contains a project that is relevant to the question and the answer. Actually the tool I linked to, automates and simplifies the process described per short by l0b0 in his answer.

My edit has been rejected for:

- *This edit introduces spam, defaces the post in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate.* (1)
- *This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.* (2)

Just to be clear. I'm not complaining here. I just want to find out the reason my edit was denied, so I don't repeat the mistake in the future.

Comment: I'd disregard the first reason, I wouldn't consider your edit as vandalism. Having said that, on Stack Overflow it seems to be frowned upon to add extra information beyond minor issues such as formatting, typos and broken links.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that if it is a link (not to docs) then the edit reviewers would need to look at the link and make sure it is not changing what the original author intended. So, it could be a radical change, depending on the link. Not sure if I've ever come across this in reviews so that's just an assumption of why it might be rejected. That said, maybe a comment with the link is better and, if you care to, mention to the author that he/she can edit in if they'd like.

Comment: I agree with the "invalid edit" reason. With a bit of expanding, your edit could be its own answer. The edit itself was just a "follow-up" to the post. I don't see how's it's spam though, that might have been a reviewer thinking it was an audit.

Comment: @gunr2171 I did not want to post a new answer because "at the core" the tool I linked to overwrites `cd` command just as the edited answer described per short. So the initial answer and my edit are somehow related from my point of view.

Comment: The "spam" reason will be because the reviewer (incorrectly) assumed you were plugging your own project. I'd have rejected as invalid too - it may well be a good suggestion but it's really more suited to a comment or fleshed out into it's own answer.

Comment: @OGHaza Even if it was my own project I don't see where is the problem, as long as the project is related with the subject in question.

Comment: @Alex, if someone offers a code based solution, and you edit their answer to include a recommendation to instead use your tool/plugin/library that is definitely a problem. Anyway that's veering off-topic. Still, in this case, imagine if you edited [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2016875/2742805) to add "Or you could do this using SuperFileCleanerProXI which will remove all those files at a button press", it would obviously be inappropriate - now this is obviously a massive exaggeration of what you did, but the reason for rejection is roughly the same.

Comment: @OGHaza Makes sense, but the situation described by you I think it occurs when there is a lack of common sense. I've tried to offer an easy and open-source alternative, but I think I got the reason behind that reject and now makes more sense for me that I should add a comment in the first place instead of edit the answer. A day when you learn something new, its not a lost day.